# Copy 3 cells from invoice to sales log sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current macro code to save and create a copy of my invoices and change inv # , TY GOOGLE !

I'm wanting to add an additional function to this, so that when i change inv # , save copy to folder , it also copies data from 3 cells of the Invoice sheet to a the SalesLog sheet i created in same workbook

So i want to copy the data from these 3 cells here from Invoice sheet

```
J4=Date  
J5=Invoice Number 
K33=Amount
```

To SalesLog sheet

```
A1=Date  
A2=Invoice Number 
A3=Amount
```

Since i will have 1000's of invoices at some point , i'd need each new copied data not to delete the prior one

Here is my current code for the module that i'd like to add to

```
Sub NextInvoice()
    Range("J5").Value = Range("J5").Value + 1
    Range("A9").MergeArea.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub SaveInvWithNewName()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    ' Copy Invoice to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    NewFN = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Invoices\" & Range("J5").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    NextInvoice
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additional variants to already posted:

**`[Range]` *to* `[Range]` *(values only)***

```
Sub SaveToSalesLog()    
    With Sheets("SalesLogSheet")
        .[A1]  = Sheets("InvoiceSheet").[J4] 
        .[A2]  = Sheets("InvoiceSheet").[J5]
        .[A3]  = Sheets("InvoiceSheet").[K33]
    End with
End Sub
```

**`Array` *to* `[Range]` *(values only)***

```
Sub test2()
    Dim I As Worksheet: Set I = Sheets("InvoiceSheet")
    Dim S As Worksheet: Set S = Sheets("SalesLogSheet")
    Dim cl As Range, x%: x = 0
    For Each cl In S.[A1:A3]
        cl.Value = Array(I.[J4], I.[J5], I.[K33])(x): x = x + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**`[Range].copy` *to* `[Range]` *(including cell format)***

```
Sub test3()
    With Sheets("InvoiceSheet")
        .[J4].Copy Worksheets("SalesLogSheet").[A1]
        .[J5].Copy Worksheets("SalesLogSheet").[A2]
        .[K33].Copy Worksheets("SalesLogSheet").[A3]
    End With
End Sub
```

**`[Range].copy` *to* `[Range]` *(values only)***

```
Sub test4()
    With Sheets("InvoiceSheet")
        .[J4].Copy: Worksheets("SalesLogSheet").[A1].PasteSpecial xlValues
        .[J5].Copy: Worksheets("SalesLogSheet").[A2].PasteSpecial xlValues
        .[K33].Copy: Worksheets("SalesLogSheet").[A3].PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [Worksheet.Range()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512.aspx) property specifying `Range` to `Range` expressions:

```
Sub SaveToSalesLog()    
    WorkSheets("SalesLogSheet").Range("A1")  = WorkSheets("InvoiceSheet").Range("J4") 
    WorkSheets("SalesLogSheet").Range("A2")  = WorkSheets("InvoiceSheet").Range("J5")
    WorkSheets("SalesLogSheet").Range("A3")  = WorkSheets("InvoiceSheet").Range("K33")
End Sub
```